# Three week from now

Tags: expressions

We say

> This day next year.
>   This day next week.

What do you say to talk about something that will happen *'this day three weeks from now'* ?
Is there a shorter way to to say it, like the above sentences?

What if you say the day like Monday? As in:

'Three weeks from now on Monday.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say

> A week today
>
> Three weeks today

but looking on GloWbE, it's pretty clear that these are British (and Commonwealth) English. In American English, the equivalent is

> A week from today
>
> Three weeks from today.

(I would never say these).

In British English we can also say

> A week next Tuesday

and even

> Tuesday week

but I don't think Americans say these much.

I'm not sure about

> A year today

but I think it works - certainly there are a few instances of this in GloWbE.

So to answer your question directly:

> Three weeks today (BrE)
>
> Three weeks from today (AmE)
>
> In three weeks' time (both).

Comment: What if you say the day, like Monday? Do you say "Three weeks Monday"  or what?

Comment: Good question, @Sharaman. For reasons I can't explain, I wouldn't say "Three weeks Monday". But I would say "Three weeks next Monday" or "Three weeks on Monday".

Comment: or even ["A year ago last Thursday"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPgo6s1lBbw)

Comment: @Sharaman in American English, it would be "Three weeks from Monday." If it's ambiguous which Monday is meant, you'd say "Three weeks from this coming Monday" or "Three weeks from this past Monday."

Comment: Americans more often say “in _n_ week[s]”, omitting “’s time”.

Comment: As an American I don't even _understand_ "A week next Tuesday" or "Tuesday week".

Comment: @MichaelHampton: now you do! ;-)

Comment: @ColinFine: Let's say today is Wednesday: isn't 'in three weeks' 18 days away from now, whereas 'in three weeks' time' is  21 days away from now? Isn't there a difference between these two time expressions?

Comment: @user58319: Why would "in three weeks" be 18 days away? Actually, both these expressions are a bit  vague. I would take "in three weeks time" to be a bit more precise, but it still might be 20 or 22 days away. "In three weeks" is less specific than that - maybe 18-24 days away.

Comment: @ColinFine: to me, 'in three weeks' means not next week (1), neither the week after next (2), but the next one (3), which begins on Monday, so Wednesday to Wednesday, twice, (14 days), + Thursday-Friday-Saturday-Sunday (4 days) = 18 days... Whereas 'in three weeks time' would mean in three times 7 days, exactly...

Comment: @user58319: So in your understanding, "in three weeks" means _precisely_ the first day of the week three from now (which you count as Monday, as I do, but some people count weeks beginning on Sunday)? That is not how I understand the phrase.

Answer (score 3):

"Three weeks today" should do the trick. You don't need to say it's the same day, because if it's in exactly three weeks then it has to be the same day. It means "three weeks *from* today", of course, but the "from" is often elided in colloquial English.